# Excel columns to rows

Tags: database, excel

I have an export of one table from a CMS (cmsms) which contains the content of a site. As the image shows all content (blocks) of every page are in one column (the content is defined in the little visible right most one in the image). The content IDs, each number representing one page, are the left most column in the image:

[image]

The reason this is about Excel (or Libreoffice or equivalent) is that I have exported that table into xls (using PHPMyadmin) so that I can use a WordPress plugin that requires xls to import and create pages.

The question is I want each individual page to be in one row. So for example 1651 in A1 and then all its content blocks in the same row, then 1652 in A2 and then all its content blocks in same row, etc.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Is all your data now in columns **A** & **B** ?

Comment: Column A has the content ID, B is just the type (all are 'String'), Column C has Content Block names, several parameter columns I won't need are next and the actual data in column G. So the data are really in A and G (with C being 'header names' that I can manually add)

Comment: I am probably confusing anybody willing to help, sorry. Not sure how to explain it. Basically everytime a new number is seen in column A (1651 for example) one row should be populated with the text seen in column G1, G2, etc. that has the same number (1651 for example)

Comment: I edited to include your image. Hopefully it's right. It looks odd. Couldn't you do one with column headers and a little more width? :)

Comment: Can you please explain more about what the desired result looks like? If a 1651 has 5 rows, how would you like the 5 text cells to be shown? As 5 separate cells in different columns? Or combined into one cell?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and help. I made a very simple before and after that probably illustrates it much better. Before: http://i.imgur.com/aV8LaCG.png  and after http://i.imgur.com/qpnMg92.png